# polynomials defined on a non-uniform and uniform lattice

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

After reading about the definition of orthogonal dual Hahn polynomials on wiki, you will find the link below. I didn't understand the following sentence :

***"In mathematics, the dual Hahn polynomials are a family of orthogonal polynomials in the Askey scheme of hypergeometric orthogonal polynomials. They are defined on a non-uniform lattice ${\displaystyle x(s)=s(s+1)} $"***

and

***The Hahn polynomials, ${\displaystyle h_{n}(x,N;\alpha ,\beta )}$, is defined on the uniform lattice ${\displaystyle x(s)=s}$***

I didn't understand why we define polynomials on a non-uniform and uniform lattice?

[Dual Hahn polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_Hahn_polynomials)

Comment: I don't even guess the intended meaning of "lattice" here.